# How to redirect assets to public, make public invisible and make lessMiddleware work

Tags: redirect, express, nginx, less, middleware

Yesterday I had a public folder with generated css, and a source folder with less

```
root
    /public
        /css
    /source
        /less
```

and a less middleware like this

```
module.exports = function (app, dir) {
    return lessMiddleware(path.join(dir, 'source', 'less'), {
        dest: path.join(dir),
        preprocess: {
            path: function(pathname, req) {
                return pathname.replace('public' + path.sep + 'css' + path.sep, '');
            }
        }
    });
};
```

It works fine, except that root dir is open, and I can get access to public folder. So, I put a NGINX as proxy, and had no problems, it denies access to root folder and redirects 'assets' to 'public'.

So I had url's like `http://localhost/assets/css/main.css`

Today I want to get rid of nginx for debug purposes. So I give static access to assets folder like this

```
if (settings.debug) {
    app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
}
```

The problem is that less middleware stopped working, because this code changes path for middleware to

```
c:\node\myproject\source\less\assets\css\main.less
```

Is there a way to redirect 'assets' to 'public' using express js standard *static* middleware? Or a standard way to substitute '/assets' with '/public' and pass this request forth?

I can do that with `app.get(...` and parse request and so on. I also can change middleware 'preprocess' directive. But I want to spend as less code as possible.

P.S.
Ok, now I can make assets work

```
if (settings.debug) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {      
        if (req.url.indexOf('/assets/') === 0) {
            req.url = req.url.replace('/assets/', '/public/');
        }
        next();
    });
}

app.use(require('./config/lessMiddlewareConfig.js')(__dirname));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

but I want to deny access to public now.

Answer (score 0):

On your server is it actually necessary to use less middleware?

I got around this, buy adding this to my deployment shell script:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css > /dev/null
```

which forces a recompile by requesting the css file directly to the node process.

Comment: In production it is better to recompile css on start, but in development mode I just force compilation every time when I change design and refresh page. I mean, I can write code that does same things, or script shell, but do not want to waste time, because this project is just a hobby.

Comment: then in development mode, don't use nginx to serve the stylesheets folder.

Comment: Yes, all folders are open now in development. It seems, that on some hostings I am not available to use nginx, and that constrict number of cheap hostings.